# Why subreports are added only in detail band and crosstabs in summary? How actually the bands are processed in Jaspersoft?

Tags: ireport

I'm using subreports in Jaspersoft. Why we have to add subreports only in detail band why not in any other band?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm new to jasper reports so can anybody provide a tutorial name or give some detail explaination?

The [iReport Ultimate Guide](https://www.jaspersoft.com/store/ireport-ultimate-guide-documentation) is very helpful guide.

> why we have to add subreports only in detail band why not in any other band?

The subreport could not be placed to the band without `overflow` support.

Answer (score 0):

The premise is not correct. It's common to put subreports in other bands.

Comment: no if i try adding subreports on other bands it gave an exception     "subreport overflowed on a band that doesnot support overflow"

Comment: For future readers of this thread: Yes, it's common to put subreports in other bands. You are claiming that some subreports cannot go in some bands under some conditions. That's true. But putting subreports in the detail band is not necessary. (And it's not sufficient either. A detail band set to horizontal filling could also throw "Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow".)